# Prefab is instantiated successfully but when accessed, generate NullReferenceException in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this initialization of a prefab:

```
GameObject e = Instantiate(entry, new Vector3(x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
```

I know that it is successfully instantiated because I can see a clone on my hierarchy. However, if I try to access it, there is a NullReferenceException. I tried this:

```
Debug.Log(e.ToString());
```

And this:

```
e.transform.SetParent (GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform);
```

But it shows this error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object StudentListController.FillList (System.String strList) (at
>   Assets/Scripts/StudentListController.cs:45)
>   StudentListController+c__Iterator5.MoveNext () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/StudentListController.cs:23)

This is the code of FillList:

```
void FillList(string strList) {
    string[] studentData;
    string[] studentList = strList.Split (';');
    int startX = -253;
    int startY = 70;
    int addX = 100;
    int addY = 30;
    for (int y = 0; y<studentList.Length; y++ ) {
        string student = studentList[y];
        studentData = student.Split(',');
        for(int x = 0; x<studentData.Length; x++) {
            string data = studentData[x];
            if (x==3) {
                data = getAgeFromBirthdate(data).ToString();
            } else if (x==4) {
                data = getSex(data).ToString();
            } 
            GameObject e = Instantiate(entry, new Vector3(startX + 100*x, startY + 40*y, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            //e.GetComponent<Text> ().text = data;
            //e.transform.SetParent (GameObject.Find("Canvas").transform);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: your e variable is not throwing the exception , seems like the exception is being thrown by strList in the FillList method of your StudentListController

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: paste the Fill method code here too , and see if newing up the strList helps , my guess is you don't new up the strList or your code is not providing it with value so it is null hence the exception

Comment: done adding the code for FillList

Comment: sorry to ask but do strList ,  studentList and studentData have value ? also try casting the Instantiate return type and don't use the as because it will fail silently , if it fails to cast  it , try it like this : (GameObject)Instantiate(.....)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have dragged and dropped anything you need in your custom components for the prefab. If you drag and drop them you should then click apply.

Comment: Yes I have dragged and drop everything